# How to properly scrape json response from reddit?

Tags: python, json, screen-scraping, reddit

I am attempting to save all "author" entries from the json linked below into a list however am very new to python. Can someone kindly point me in the right direction?

the json: https://codebeautify.org/jsonviewer/cb0d0a91

Trying to scrape a reddit thread:

```
import requests
import json

url ="https://www.reddit.com/r/easternshoremd/comments/72u501/going_to_be_in_the_easton_area_for_work_next_week.json"

r = requests.get(url, headers={'User-agent': 'Chrome'})
d = r.json()

scrapedids = []

for child in d['data']['children']:
    scrapedids.append(child['data']['author'])

print (scrapedids)
```

If I switch the url from a reddit post to the subreddit then it works. For example, if I set

```
url = ("https://www.reddit.com/r/easternshoremd.json")
```

I believe the issue is my lack of understanding in the directory/tree (whatever it's called) of json. I've been hung up for a few hours and appreciate any assistance.

The error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/usr/PycharmProjects/untitled/delete.py", line 14, in 
    for child in d['data']['children']:
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: Either `d` is a list, or `d['data']` is a list. You can find out which by adding print(d), then print(d['data']) below where d is created.

Comment: If you look in the json, you see that ths base json object is a list, whera 'data' is in the firste entry. So you can just add [0] betwen child and ['data'].

Answer (score 2):

You included a link to the JSON, which is good. It shows that the root is an array.

Therefore your code should look more like:

```
import requests
import json

url ="https://www.reddit.com/r/easternshoremd/comments/72u501/going_to_be_in_the_easton_area_for_work_next_week.json"

r = requests.get(url, headers={'User-agent': 'Chrome'})
listings = r.json()

scrapedids = []

for listing in listings:
    for child in listing['data']['children']:
        scrapedids.append(child['data']['author'])

print (scrapedids)
```

Note that I renamed `d` to `listings` which relates to the `kind` attribute ('listing').

Comment: Works great. I thank you very much and am ver grateful for your assistance. I appreciate your time and effort to help a little guy. Have a good day.